# QT include python

Tags: python, c++, qt, qt-creator

Today i used python example [1](https://github.com/dsavard/TI_BLE_C254x):https://github.com/dsavard/TI_BLE_C254x, i want to do it on QT creator,i am trying to embed python in my c++ code in my qt project ,what can i do?

How do i include python do it?

Is there a good reference? Thank you.

I am useful to implement `Popen` to see, but can not complete its action.
Just touch QT, not familiar with.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look on [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and on [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to increase the likelihood of getting your question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definitive reference, *not QT specific*, is at https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/embedding.html

You may also need to read the [Python/C API Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/index.html#c-api-index)